# How to avoid trailing space being replaced with %20 when downloading a file with WinSACP

Tags: winscp

I use WinSCP script to download a file from an SFTP site. The file has length of trailing space after the file name.

After it is downloaded to local computer `%20` is appended to the file name. For example, `file.txt_________` becomes `file.txt________%20` on local computer (`_` stands for space).

Could you know any command I can put on the WinSCP script to remove it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Add [`-rawtransfersettings ReplaceInvalidChars=0` to your `get` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_get#rawtransfersettings):

```
get file directory\ -rawtransfersettings ReplaceInvalidChars=0
```

Read about [raw transfer options](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/rawtransfersettings).

You will lose the trailing spaces though, this way.